# Difference between __file__ and sys.argv[0]

Tags: python

Is there any difference between:

`__file__`

and

`sys.argv[0]`

Because both seem to be doing the same thing: they hold the name of the script.

If there is no difference, then why is it that `__file__` is used in almost all someplaces whereas I have never seen `sys.argv[0]` being used.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`__file__` is the name of the current file, which may be different from the main script if you are inside a module or if you start a script using `execfile()` rather than by invoking `python scriptname.py`.  `__file__`  is generally your safer bet.

Comment: sys.argv[0] may even be a module name rather than a file name if your script was executed with the `-m` switch, or a directory or zipfile name if you are using bundled execution.

Comment: Isn't \__file\__ supposed to be private and therefore not queried directly?

Comment: @Tiago No, it's fine to access it directly.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689983/279627.

Answer (score 6):

It's only the same if you are in the "main" script of your python programm. If you import other files, `__file__` will contain the path to that file, but sys.argv will still hold the same values.

Answer (score 3):

It's like Sven said.

```
MiLu@Dago: /tmp > cat file.py
import sys
import blub
print __file__
print sys.argv[0]

MiLu@Dago: /tmp > cat blub.py
import sys
print "BLUB: " + __file__
print "BLUB: " + sys.argv[0]

MiLu@Dago: /tmp > python file.py
BLUB: /tmp/blub.pyc
BLUB: file.py
file.py
file.py
```

I thought that `__file__` was replaced with the filename during a preprocessor step. I was not 100 % sure that's actually the case in Python - but it is in [C/C++](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231043) and Perl. In Python, this might be different as the `__file__` is also correct for compiled Python files (`pyc`), and there doesn't seem to be any trace of the filename in that file's contents.

Comment: Ludwig: Probably you should do some more experimentation. Create an empty file named `empty.py`. At the Python interactive prompt, enter this line: `import empty; print(empty.__file__); reload(empty); print(empty.__file__)` ... then edit your answer.

Comment: Ludwig: Facts: `__file__` is an attribute of the module, created automatically when the module is loaded. CPython doesn't have a preprocessor step.

Answer (score 0):

Actually argv[0] might be a script name or a full path to the script + script name, depending on the os.

Here's the entry in official documentation http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether your *.py code is running as a module or as the main script!

`__file__` is the current file which may be inside a module and not the main script, which is called sys.argv[0].

It's useful because you can have code, like a main block, tests, etc. in a file that only runs if it's NOT being used in a module aka it's the main script

```
if __file__.endswith(sys.argv[0]):
    #you're the main script
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to do `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: yes, I was just using the terms in the op's question