# Why do some functions have underscores "__" before and after the function name?

Tags: python, function, methods, double-underscore

This "underscoring" seems to occur a lot, and I was wondering if this was a requirement in the Python language, or merely a matter of convention?

Also, could someone name and explain which functions tend to have the underscores, and why (`__init__`, for instance)?

Comment: @AustinHenley: Not for double underscores before *and after* the name. You're thinking of underscores solely *before* the name.

Comment: Related: ["What is the historical reason why Python uses the double underscore for Class Private members?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/228216/what-is-the-historical-reason-why-python-uses-the-double-underscore-for-class-pr).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: @MackM Note that this question asks about underscores *before and after* the name, and the duplicate target that you proposed asks about underscores only *before* the name. Though, I admit that some of the answers there cover this case as well.

Answer (score 790, accepted):

From the [Python PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> #### [Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)
>
> The following special forms using leading or trailing underscores are
>   recognized (these can generally be combined with any case convention):
>
> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   `Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`
> - `__double_leading_underscore`: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, `__boo` becomes `_FooBar__boo`; see below).
> - `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces.  E.g. `__init__`,
>     `__import__` or `__file__`.  Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

Note that names with double leading and trailing underscores are essentially reserved for Python itself: "Never invent such names; only use them as documented".

Comment: Raymond also explains why you'd want the name mangling behavior starting at around 34 minutes into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg

Comment: So the choice between the single leading underscore and double leading underscore in a name is a bit like choosing between protected and private in C++ and Java? _single_leading_underscore can be changed by children, but __double_leading_underscore can't?

Comment: `__double_leading_underscore` is *still public*, the variable is simply renamed to avoid a clash.

Comment: The new mangled method name, having a single leading underscore, is private. E.g. `__boo` becomes `_FooBar__boo`

Comment: Talking about "double leading and trailing underscores" part of the answer, what does "magic" mean here?  When you say "use them as documented", what am I using them for?   Did you mean, "These are a methods which python is meant to call, not you" ?

Comment: @BenSlade I think the crucial part is "Never invent such names". If you write `class Thing: def __foo__(self): ...`, the Python developers may add the magic method `__foo__` to the definition of `object` in a new Python version and whatever that method is supposed to do won't work for your `Thing` after updating Python.

Answer (score 88):

The other respondents are correct in describing the double leading and trailing underscores as a naming convention for "special" or "magic" methods.

While you can call these methods directly (`[10, 20].__len__()` for example), the presence of the underscores is a hint that these methods are intended to be invoked indirectly (`len([10, 20])` for example).  Most python operators have an associated "magic" method (for example, `a[x]` is the usual way of invoking `a.__getitem__(x)`).

Answer (score 33):

Names surrounded by double underscores are "special" to Python. They're listed in the [Python Language Reference, section 3, "Data model"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: Finally, a fast pointer from Google to the right part of the Python reference manual. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

**Added an example to understand the use of __ in python. Here is the list of All __**

**https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-all.html#_**

> Certain classes of identifiers (besides keywords) have special
>   meanings. Any use of ***** names, in any other context, that does not
>   follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without
>   warning

Access restriction using __

```
"""
Identifiers:
-  Contain only (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
-  Start with a lowercase letter or _.
-  Single leading _ :  private
-  Double leading __ :  strong private
-  Start & End  __ : Language defined Special Name of Object/ Method
-  Class names start with an uppercase letter.
-

"""


class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, name, money, password):
        self.name = name            # Public
        self._money = money         # Private : Package Level
        self.__password = password  # Super Private

    def earn_money(self, amount):
        self._money += amount
        print("Salary Received: ", amount, " Updated Balance is: ", self._money)

    def withdraw_money(self, amount):
        self._money -= amount
        print("Money Withdraw: ", amount, " Updated Balance is: ", self._money)

    def show_balance(self):
        print(" Current Balance is: ", self._money)


account = BankAccount("Hitesh", 1000, "PWD")  # Object Initalization

# Method Call
account.earn_money(100)

# Show Balance
print(account.show_balance())

print("PUBLIC ACCESS:", account.name)  # Public Access

# account._money is accessible because it is only hidden by convention
print("PROTECTED ACCESS:", account._money)  # Protected Access

# account.__password will throw error but account._BankAccount__password will not
# because __password is super private
print("PRIVATE ACCESS:", account._BankAccount__password)

# Method Call
account.withdraw_money(200)

# Show Balance
print(account.show_balance())

# account._money is accessible because it is only hidden by convention
print(account._money)  # Protected Access
```

Comment: Is there a place that documents the use of leading `__` as `strong private`? I don't see it in the linked document, nor under the link in that document to [`__` identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). Single leading underscore is documented there; double leading underscore for class private names using name mangling is documented there; but it seems calling `__` "super private" is misleading, and may lead to people using it on file-level functions, where as far as I know it actually has no meaning.

Answer (score 7):

Actually I use _ method names when I need to differ between parent and child class names. I've read some codes that used this way of creating parent-child classes. As an example I can provide this code:

```
class ThreadableMixin:
   def start_worker(self):
       threading.Thread(target=self.worker).start()

   def worker(self):
      try:
        self._worker()
    except tornado.web.HTTPError, e:
        self.set_status(e.status_code)
    except:
        logging.error("_worker problem", exc_info=True)
        self.set_status(500)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(self.async_callback(self.results))
```

...

and the child that have a _worker method

```
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, ThreadableMixin):
   def _worker(self):
      self.res = self.render_string("template.html",
        title = _("Title"),
        data = self.application.db.query("select ... where object_id=%s", self.object_id)
    )
```

...

Comment: Isn't this what the double underscore prefix is for?

Answer (score 5):

This convention is used for special variables or methods (so-called “magic method”) such as `__init__` and `__len__`. These methods provides special syntactic features or do special things.

For example, `__file__` indicates the location of Python file, `__eq__` is executed when `a == b` expression is executed.

A user of course can make a custom special method, which is a very rare case, but often might modify some of the built-in special methods (e.g. you should initialize the class with `__init__` that will be executed at first when an instance of a class is created).

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):  # use special method '__init__' for initializing
        self.a = a
    def __custom__(self):  # custom special method. you might almost do not use it
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the use of an underscore in a function name indicates that the function is intended for internal use and should not be called directly by users. It is a convention used to indicate that the function is "private" and not part of the public API of the module. However, it is not enforced by the language and can still be called by the user if they choose to do so.