# Calling private function within the same class python

Tags: python, function, call, private

How can I call a private function from some other function within the same class?

```
class Foo:
  def __bar(arg):
    #do something
  def baz(self, arg):
    #want to call __bar
```

Right now, when I do this:

```
__bar(val)
```

from baz(), I get this:

```
NameError: global name '_Foo__createCodeBehind' is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what the reason of the error is?
Also, how can I call a private function from another private function?

Comment: It does not actually matter here that the function is "private" (this is not real privacy anyway). The problem should have been obvious, anyway: where the code says `def baz(self, arg):`, *why does it not* say `def baz(arg):`? Now, why wouldn't the same logic apply to `__bar`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel stating anything as obvious to someone else is admitting one does not have adequate experience working on a team. This is one of the primary underlying reasons for peer review. See also "agile restrospective prime directive".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no implicit `this->` in Python like you have in C/C++ etc. You have to call it on `self`.

```
class Foo:
     def __bar(self, arg):
         #do something
     def baz(self, arg):
         self.__bar(arg)
```

---

These methods are not *really* private though. When you start a method name with two underscores Python does some name mangling to make it "private" and that's all it does, it does not enforce anything like other languages do. If you define `__bar` on `Foo`, it is still accesible from outside of the object through `Foo._Foo__bar`. E.g., one can do this:

```
f = Foo()
f._Foo__bar('a')
```

This explains the "odd" identifier in the error message you got as well.

You can find it [`here`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in the docs.

Comment: Consider that making methods private is a communication to developers about how to use the class. Its fine that many languages do not enforce the prevention of access to private members, as the fact that the method is marked as private tells developers not to use the class or instance that way. Developers just need to consider the public interface.

Answer (score 12):

`__bar` is "private" (in the sense that its name has been [mangled](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)), but it's still a method of `Foo`, so you have to reference it via `self` and pass `self` to it. Just calling it with a bare `__bar()` won't work; you have to call it like so: `self.__bar()`. So...

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __bar(self, arg):
...     print '__bar called with arg ' + arg
...   def baz(self, arg):
...     self.__bar(arg)
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.baz('a')
__bar called with arg a
```

You can access `self.__bar` anywhere within your `Foo` definition, but once you're outside the definition, you have to use `foo_object._Foo__bar()`. This helps avoid namespace collisions in the context of class inheritance.

If that's not why you're using this feature, you might reconsider using it. The convention for creating "private" variables and methods in Python is to [prepend an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689983/577088) to the name. This has no syntactic significance, but it conveys to users of your code that the variable or method is part of implementation details that may change.