# unable to call member function in class python

Tags: python

I am on python 2.7 and trying to call a member function from another function which is located within same class.

```
class Foo:
     
     def bar(self):
         print 'correctly called'
         
     def baz(self):
         self.bar
    
  
a = Foo()
a.baz()
```

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145499/calling-private-function-within-the-same-class-python) question and wrote a sample class as above, but still not able to print `"correctly called"` located in function `bar`. This may sound little noob but I think this is the only way to call a member function or am I doing anything wrong?

**What I want**

I simply want to call print statement located in `bar` function from another member function `baz` within same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function, employ parentheses:

```
class Foo:
     def bar(self):
         print('correctly called')

     def baz(self):
         self.bar() # <-- ()
```

When you write `self.bar`, this is an expression evaluating to a function object. This is useful if you want to pass the function object to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#map) and the like.

Comment: sorry I totally missed it. thanks for answer and edit. I understood what and why it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Call a method with `()`:

```
self.bar()
```

`self.bar` is the access to this object. Need the parentheses to actually call it.

Comment: Thanks this solved it.

Comment: @phihag sorry for late accepting. At first it asked me to wait for 12 minutes and after that I totally forgot. I have done it now. Thanks for efforts.