# How to call a private (file scope) function from a class define in the same file

Tags: python

In one file I define a class and a private function. I want to call this function within a method. What is the syntax to reference the "outerscope" of the class and tell python where my function lives? (:

#### Actual example that do not work:

```
def __private_function():
    pass

class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        __private_function()
```

Error: `NameError: name '_MyClass__private_function' is not defined`

#### Nb:

Similar but not a duplicate of [Calling private function within the same class python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145499/calling-private-function-within-the-same-class-python).

Comment: have you tried using single underscore? it would avoid name mangling.

Comment: I have to say I'm actually quite surprised by this behaviour :-/  Now there are actually very few reasons to use the double-leading-underscores name mangling mechanism, and specially not for plain functions. The convention is to use one single leading underscore for "implementation" stuff (consider this as the python equivalent of "protected").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single underscore to avoid name mangling.

```
def _private_function():
    print('use single underscore to avoid name mangling.')

class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        _private_function()

a = MyClass()
a.my_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
globals()['__private_function']()
```

But if you can, just don't name the function with two underscores. I don't think there's any good reason outside of a class.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I don't require name mangling for this case, but its good to know you can still access it.