# Python 3: Why am I getting an AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm running Python 3 and I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AssemblyParser' object has no attribute 'hasMoreCommands'
```

Here is the code that is raising the error:

```
import sys
from Parser import AssemblyParser
from Code import Code

parser = AssemblyParser(sys.argv[1])
translator = Code()

out_file = str(sys.argv[1]).split(".")
out_file = str(out_file[:1]) + ".hack"

with open(out_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while parser.hasMoreCommands():
        parser.advance()
        if parser.commandType() == "A_COMMAND":
            dec_num = parser.symbol()
            binary = "{0:b}".format(dec_num)
        elif parser.commandType() == "C_COMMAND":
            default_bits = "111"
            comp_bits += translator.comp(parser.comp())
            dest_bits += translator.dest(parser.dest())
            jump_bits += translator.jump(parser.jump())
            binary = default_bits + comp_bits + dest_bits + jump_bits
        assert len(binary) == 16
        f.write(binary)
```

Here is my Parser.py file:

```
class AssemblyParser:
"""
Encapsulates access to the input code. Reads an assembly language command, 
parses it, and provides convenient access to the command's components (fields and symbols).
In addition, removes all whitespace and comments.
"""

def __init__(self, input_file):
    self.current_command = ""
    self.next_command = ""
    with open(input_file,"r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for l in f:
            line = "".join(l.split()) # Remove whitespace from the line
            line = line.split('//') # Removes any comments from the line
            clean_line = line[0]
            if clean_line.strip(): # Removes any blank lines
                f.write(clean_line)
        next_command = f.readline()


def __hasMoreCommands__(self):
    if self.next_command:
        return true
    return false


def __advance__(self):
    with open(input_file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        self.current_command = self.next_command
        self.next_command = f.readline()


def __commandType__(self):
    char_1 = self.current_command[:1]
    if char_1 == "@":
        return "A_COMMAND"
    elif char_1 == "(":
        return "L_COMMAND"
    else:
        return "C_COMMAND"


def __symbol__(self):
    assert self.commandType() == ("A_COMMAND" or "L_COMMAND")

    if self.commandType() == "A_COMMAND":
        symbol = str(symbol[1:])
    else:
        symbol = str(symbol[1:len(symbol)-1])
    return str(symbol)


def __dest__(self):
    assert self.commandType() == "C_COMMAND"

    if "=" in self.current_command:
        temp = self.current_command.split("=")
        return str(temp[:1])
    else:
        return ""


def __comp__(self):
    assert self.commandType() == "C_COMMAND"

    temp = self.current_command

    if "=" in temp:
        temp = temp.split("=")
        temp = str(temp[1:])
    if ";" in temp:
        temp = temp.split(";")
        temp = str(temp[:1])
    return temp


def __jump__(self):
    assert self.commandType() == "C_COMMAND"

    if ";" in self.current_command:
        temp = self.current_command.split(";")
        return str(temp[1:])
    else:
        return ""
```

I really don't know why I'm getting this error, I've looked at the import documentation, but I'm getting more and more confused. I'm fairly new to Python. Can anyone explain this error?

Thanks.

Comment: `hasMoreCommands` vs `__hasMoreCommands__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. There seems to be no function in Parser module with name hasMoreCommand. The function in there starts with underscore and end eith underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Two leading and trailing underscores are used to identify "magic" attributes. You can't use that to create your own, as they only reference pre-existing methods.

The following is what you probably want:

```
hasMoreCommands():
```

If you have multiple classes with this function, use name mangling instead:

```
_hasMoreCommands():
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689983/2030480

And: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html