# The behavior of variable and function with leading underscore in a class in Python

Tags: python

When we use `from <module/package> import *`, none of the names that start with a `_` will be imported unless the module’s/package’s `__all__` list explicitly contains them.

Is this not applicable to variables and functions of a class?

From the below programs, it seems it's not applicable to variables and function inside a class.

`_bar` and `_check_func` both are executed in `test_import.py`. However, `_test_func()` throws an error for having leading underscore. Am I missing anything here?

**test_var.py**

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar=15
    def test_mod(self):
        print("this is test mod function")
    def _check_func(self):
        print("this is _check_func function")

def _test_func():
    print("this is test function var 2")
```

**test_import.py**

```
from test_var import *

p1=test()
print(p1._bar)
p1.test_mod()
p1._check_func()

_test_func()
```

**Output:**

```
15
this is test mod function
this is _check_func function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_import.py", line 8, in <module>
    _test_func()
NameError: name '_test_func' is not defined
```

Comment: By convention class members with a single underscore at the front are to be treated as the equivalent of private members in other languages and are not to be used by code outside the class. However this is not imposed by the language, but in any  case wise programmers obey the convention.

Comment: the first answer have nice expclication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689964/why-do-some-functions-have-underscores-before-and-after-the-function-name

Comment: That makes sense. Since class members with leading underscore need to be treated as private members, it should not be used outside of the class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The underscore rule is imposed by the importer when it sees `from test_var import *`. In fact, the functions are still in the module namespace and you can still use them:

```
import test_var
test_var._test_func()
```

You don't import class methods, just classes so the underscore rule isn't applied. `p1._check_func()` works for the same reason that `test_var._test_func()` works: You addressed the variable in its namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You imported `test` and are accessing its members (with or without underscores) through that namespace (in your example, through the instantiated object `p1`). `test` is what you `import`, `test._bar` is only accessible through `test` and is not among the `import`ed symbols.