# Can someone please explain what is the difference between __init or __init__ (one has only two underscores before and the other has four underscores)?

Tags: python, methods, init

**FIRST ONE**

```js
class Animal():
    def __init(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        pass
```

**THE OTHER ONE:**

```js
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth

    def getArea(self):
        print(self.length*self.breadth, "is area of Rectangle")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some functions have underscores "\_\_" before and after the function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689964/why-do-some-functions-have-underscores-before-and-after-the-function-name)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the first one is concerned I am not sure if I have seen it anywhere but for the second one the `__init__` is a reserved method in python classes. It is called a constructor in object-oriented terminology. This method is called when an object is created from a class and it allows the class to initialize the attributes of the class. For more info check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__init__-in-python/) link

Answer (score 0):

It seems I got confused, I am having python course and it seems this is only name of a definition in class and **init** is understandable..

Thank you for your time, I do appreciate the answer!
It was my bad that cost me 30min or searching something that doesn't exist......
My bad...