# How to read config file from module and from main file?

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.x, configparser

I've a problem with loading and reading my config file. When I running the `imptest.py` file then Python read `configfile.cfg` and I get following output:

```
D:\tmp\test\dir1>python imptest.py
Section1
Section2
Section3
```

But when I running the `mainfile.py` file then nothing happens and seems that Python don't read the `configfile.cfg` file:

```
D:\tmp\test>python mainfile.py

D:\tmp\test>
```

My structure of directories:

```
test/
 dir1/
    __init__.py
    imptest.py
 static/
    configfile.cfg
 mainfile.py
```

Source of `mainfile.py` file:

```py
from dir1.imptest import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Source of `imptest.py` file:

```py
import configparser

def run():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('../static/configfile.cfg', encoding='utf8')

    for sections in config.sections():
        print (sections)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Source of `configfile.cfg` file:

```
[Section1]
Foo = bar
Port = 8081

[Section2]
Bar = foo
Port = 8080

[Section3]
Test = 123
Port = 80
```

**Edited**

So far my solution (absolute paths) is:

```
cwd = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + os.path.sep + '..')
config.read(os.path.join(cwd,'static' + os.path.sep + 'configfile.cfg'), encoding='utf8')
```

Is it better, worse or the same as solution by @Yavar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a relative path to `imptest.py`, use `__file__`:

```
mydir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_path = os.path.join(mydir, '..', rest_of_the_path)
```

Also, see the answers to this question:
[Difference between __file__ and sys.argv[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851588/difference-between-file-and-sys-argv0)

Comment: Thx! It's working but I wonder if my solution is better, worse or the same as your?

Comment: Looks about the same to me. My only note is that `os.path.join` takes care of joining multiple path components, so you don't really need `os.path.sep`.

Comment: It seems that your solution is better. I tested it and it works great and exactly that as I expected. Thank you very much for your help. +1 for you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

it is not finding your config file because you are not using the correct path when called from your mainfile version.

interestingly, configparser silently ignores.  check this out:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 10 2012, 18:14:40) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import configparser
>>> 
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read('doesnotexist.cfg')
[]
>>> print(config.sections())
[]
>>>
```