# "Failed to execute script" error in executable file created by innosetup

Tags: python, exe, inno-setup, distribution, software-distribution

I created a simple script like the following.

This simply creates a text.txt file in the same location as the executable.

**test.py**

```
import os,sys
test_str = "test"

exeFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
path_w =  os.path.join(exeFileDir, 'test.txt')
with open(path_w, mode='w') as f:
    f.write(test_str)
```

And I created an exe file using Pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller --noconsole test.py
```

At this point, running the exe file ran the code correctly and created a test.txt file.

Finally, I created a setup file using innosetup.

However, when I ran exe after running innosetup, I got the following error.

[image]

It seems that innosetup caused such an error. What caused it?

My innosetup configuration file is as follows.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "testApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.00"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "test.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{3D8E37F3-FB32-4AF9-8C64-58C37D542248}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\taichi\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Desktop\dist\test\test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Desktop\dist\test\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: See [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

Comment: Thank you. I changed to write data to the AppData / Roaming folder this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*It seems that innosetup caused such an error. What caused it?*"

**No, the error comes from the python script !!** [pyinstaller : Failed to execute script](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2015)

__ file __ is the name of the **current file**, which may be different from the `main script` if you are inside a module or if you start a script using execfile()

[Difference between --file-- and sys.argv[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851588/difference-between-file-and-sys-argv0)

**test.exe** vs **test.py**

os.path.abspath(**sys.argv[0]**) **may fail** if not also **test.py** is in the same folder as **test.exe**

```
exeFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

To get the `dirname` of the absolute path, use

```
exeFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

and now `path_w` should be correct

```
path_w =  os.path.join(exeFileDir, 'test.txt')
```